# unable to render CDN link images in jspdf using AddHTML

Tags: jspdf

I am using `addHtml` to export div content as `pdf` with  local images. It is working awesome, but images which have cdn links(server images) are not rendering.

The code which I have tried:

```
<div id="testdiv"> <asp:Image ImageUrl="https://test.com/DOCS/b11.jpg"Width="200px" runat="server" />
```

```
function exportChartToPDF() {
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'A3', true);        
        doc.internal.scaleFactor = 3.75;
        var styles1 = {
            pagesplit: true,
            'background': '#fff'         
        };
        doc.addHTML($('#divpdf'), 0, 10, styles1, function () {
            doc.save('test.pdf');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Any errors/warnings in console? Not sure how exactly jspdf works, but if it does anything like reading image data via script or trying to paint it onto a canvas element, then make sure your images are CORS-enabled.

Comment: where we have to enable cors is in server(iis)?? If you can help me, i would be so relieve, thanks

Comment: if it is in hosted application i already enabled cors

Comment: Well the origin server would have to enable that, so in this case `test.com`. (If that actually is the problem here, no guarantee.)

Answer (score 0):

```
     var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt',  [PDF_Width, PDF_Height]);

    html2canvas($(".html_pdf_filemain")[0],
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top,

    { // y coord
        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
        //'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers,


    },
     {allowTaint:true}).then(function(canvas) {
     canvas.getContext('2d');

      console.log(canvas.height+"  "+canvas.width);


      var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);



      pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, top_left_margin+100,canvas_image_width,canvas_image_height);


      for (var i = 1; i <= totalPDFPages; i++) {

      pdf.addPage(PDF_Width, PDF_Height);
      pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, (-(PDF_Height*i)+ 
     (top_left_margin*4))+100,canvas_image_width,canvas_image_height);
    }

          var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
          iframe.setAttribute('style','position:absolute;right:0; top:0; bottom:0; height:100%; width:650px; padding:20px;');
          document.body.appendChild(iframe);
          iframe.src = pdf.output('datauristring');
          // pdf.save("HTML-Document.pdf");
         },margins);
       };
```

this is my generated pdf
[image: generated pdf]